# Future according to a deceased programmer

Tags: story-identification, novel

A deceased computer software co. Owner causes special glasses to be made that allow the wearer to identify other insiders. Computer multiplayer gamers perform tasks as directed by the dead genius to gain points and real money to change society. Few see the big picture.

Comment: When did you read it? What language was it in? Do you remember anything about the cover, or any of the characters (descriptions, names, genders, etc)? Was it aimed at any particular age group?

Comment: Also, were the tasks performed in the real world or in the multiplayer game? And what do you mean by "insiders"?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! As phantom42 said, it would really help to know some more details about this novel. You might also like to check out [our](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/31394) [guidance](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9336/31394) on asking story-ID questions.

Comment: @Hypnosifl - tasks were definitely performed in the real world, in _Daemon_.

Comment: See http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/114536/4918 "Story about brain implants that were similar to Google Glasses" which may or may not be related.

Answer (score 5):

From a general standpoint I can think of a couple involving VR. There is a series done by the writer of The Maze Runner for YA Fiction. But what really comes to mine is Daemon by Daniel Suarez.

A brilliant programmer and game developer dying from brain cancer gets the idea humanity needs a new world order. To that extent, he creates a daemon that activates upon his death, killing 2 other programmers that unknowingly aided in its creation. The daemon then proceeds to secure financial assets and manufacturing resources by taking over hundreds of companies and creation of automated Cars, Motorcyles and a variety of other devices. Operatives are recruited via a game that using the aforementioned classes and also have their own network called the Darknet.

Phantom Edit-
There is a sequel novel to this called Freedom which culminates in an epic show down by the Daemon and it's physical world proxies against a govt task force and associated mercenaries looking to shut it down. I liked it but it didn't feel as good compared to Daemon.

Comment: Welcome to SF&F! This answer could really be improved by adding the details from these stories that makes you think they are a match.

Comment: Definitely [_Daemon_](http://www.amazon.com/Daemon-Daniel-Suarez-ebook/dp/B003QP4NPE/ref=la_B001V206AK_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1459390028&sr=1-1).