# TV Series (I think) about wireless internet implants gone deadly

Tags: story-identification, tv, brain-implant

I was reading [another `story-identification` question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114536/story-about-brain-implants-that-were-similar-to-google-glasses?rq=1), when this suddenly popped into my head. I'm pretty sure it was a TV series that I saw being advertised about six years ago. The basic premise was that there was an implant that gave you a wireless Internet connection in your brain. I don't think there was an overlay in your vision, hyper-fast brain processing, or anything like that, more that you could do a search query at the speed of thought, with much the same issue of search engines today where the results may not be the absolute truth. Anyhow, it becomes one of those things that everyone has to have, with only the poor and a few opposed folk opting out, right up until the beginning of the series, when suddenly everyone with the implant dies, leaving a much-reduced population. I didn't actually get to watch it, just see some ads, so I don't really know how the plot turned out, although I have this vague idea that India was a main focal-point, either because they had a substantial population that did not have implants (because they couldn't afford the technology / surgery) or because almost everyone had them (because the government had subsidized it).

I have a vague idea that much of the plot involved a combination of figuring out how to survive with so many people involved in infrastructure dying, and trying to solve the mystery of what happened to kill everyone, and if it was an accident or an intentional act. I also think it was a short title, one or two words. I don't think it lasted more than a season or two.

I will, of course, add more details as I can recall them.

Comment: Agg, I think I remember this too but can't remember what is actually WAS.  I vaguely remember one of the first scenes occuring in a parking garage or something (or a character driving into one when whatever happened hit?) but I could be confusing that scene with something else.

Comment: Could it have been a digital (YouTube) series?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%2B:_The_Digital_Series?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This could be the web series [H+: The Digital Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%2B:_The_Digital_Series) from August 2012 to January 2013.  There was only one series of 48 ~5 minute [YouTube episodes](https://www.youtube.com/user/HplusDigitalSeries) with an announced, but unproduced, second season.

> The series is based on a future where one-third of the world's population has a neural implant named H+, which connects the human mind to the Internet 24 hours a day. The implant was created by a company called Hplus Nano Teoranta, an Irish biotechnology company founded with the intent of improving the medical sector with technology. The story begins in *medias res*, depicting the effects of a virus which infects the H+ implant. Concurrent episodes go back and forward in time to different settings, and various characters' viewpoints are used to tell the story.

[Bryan Singer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bryan_Singer) was involved in the production and several well-known genre actors were in it.

As I recall, the first episode (the only one I watched) involved a couple driving in a parking garage.  The husband was (illegally) checking sports highlights while driving.  He dies when "the incident" happens, but she happens to be in a dead zone with several other people in the garage surviving.

Looking at the episode list, several are set in Mumbai.

[YouTube Channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/HplusDigitalSeries) trailer:

Comment: I think you have it. Thank you. That one was bugging me.